# html5 mobile websites with multiple scrolling sections

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have been developing a mobile website that has two sections that have to scroll. The main page content and the nav section content. The nav bar is toggled in and out of view using jquery animate, for user friendliness.
When the page loads the heights of both sections are set to the height/width of the device depending on orientation, this is why they need to scroll individually.

On my mobile device (android - with multiple browsers) I can scroll the main page content as I should be able to but when I try and scroll the nav section this also scrolls the main page content instead. Why is this? The two sections are set up with overflow set to scroll.

```
#page{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    z-index:2;
overflow:scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
#nav{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    top:70px; //there is a header and footer overlaying
    left:0px;
    display:none;
    background-color:rgba(51,51,51,1);
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    overflow:scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px #333;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Is there something I have overlooked or a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you probably want the position of your #nav to be relative and **set a `z-index` on your #nav of 3 or higher.** If I build a mobile website, I want to make the user feels like he is using an native app.

To have more control of the scrolling abilities, you can try the following.

Disable all scrolling:

```
//create the exception variable.
var Scrollable = '.scrollable';

    //prevent all scrolling.
    $(document).on('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('body').on('touchstart', Scrollable, function(e) {
        if (e.currentTarget.scrollTop === 0) {
            e.currentTarget.scrollTop = 1;
        } else if (e.currentTarget.scrollHeight === e.currentTarget.scrollTop + e.currentTarget.offsetHeight) {
            e.currentTarget.scrollTop -= 1;
        }
    });
```

The following is to allow scrolling on the exception:

```
    // Stops preventDefault from being called on document if it sees a scrollable div
    $('body').on('touchmove', Scrollable, function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

What you want to do, is set a class called `scrollable` on every element that you want to be scrollable.

This way you can easily decide if you want something to be scrollable or not, overflow is not always working as you think it would.

I hope this helps.